# Array of HashSets with comparer in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, hashset, icomparer

as the title says, i have an array of hashsets, but i don't know how apply to them a comparer. Like this:

```
//This Works:
public HashSet<Animal.AnimalCell>UpdateList = new HashSet<Animal.AnimalCell>(new CellComparer());
//This Does not work: 
public HashSet<Animal.AnimalCell>[]UpdateListThreaded = new HashSet<Animal.AnimalCell>(new CellComparer())[10];
//This Does not Work :
public HashSet<Animal.AnimalCell>[]UpdateListThreaded = new HashSet<Animal.AnimalCell>[10](new CellComparer());
//This Works:
public HashSet<Animal.AnimalCell>[]UpdateListThreaded = new HashSet<Animal.AnimalCell>[10];
```

Of Course i need the comparer.. What am i doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an array of `HashSet<T>`, you need to initialize each element in the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < UpdateList.Length; i++)
{
    UpdateList[i] = new HashSet<AnimalCell>(new CellComparer());
}
```